# Error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length (4 times)"

Tags: r, regression, lm

I have encountered this error in this specific part of this code which calls this Models variable.

```r
Data$currRet[PGsLocs] <- predict.lm(Models[[paste0("Retention", as.character(PGs[i]))]], 
                                        newdata = newdata_subset
    )
```

This line is part of a larger function but i managed to limit the issue to this specific line.

Im not sure why as i've tried to rewrite the Models function multiple times.

Issue Line :

```r
Data$currRet[PGsLocs] <- predict.lm(Models[[paste0("Retention", as.character(PGs[i]))]], 
                                        newdata = newdata_subset
    )
```

Underlying Modeld Variable :

```r
Models <- lapply(1:dim(RetentionTablediff_2)[2], function(x) {
  model <- lm(RetentionTablediff_2[,x] ~ PriceTablediff_2[,x] + YOYTablediff_2[,x], data = Combinedtable_2)
})
```